# microtype, listings and lrbox: What in the world is going on here?

Tags: listings, boxes, microtype

The image says it all:

[image]

I'm not sure what's going on, but it seems that `microtype` "breaks" the `lrbox` hack for coloring `\lstinline`. The code is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings,xparse,xcolor,microtype}

\lstset{
    basicstyle = \ttfamily,
    columns = fullflexible,
}

\newsavebox\mybox

\DeclareDocumentCommand \boxlst{ O{} v } {%
    \microtypesetup{disable}%           Disable microtype for this piece of code
    \begin{lrbox}{\mybox}%              Put the listing in an lrbox
    \lstinline[#1]@#2@%                 Make the listing
    \end{lrbox}%
    {\colorbox{yellow}{\unhbox\mybox}}% Typeset the listing in a yellow box
    \microtypesetup{enable}%            Re-enable microtype
}

% Uncommenting the following line -- i.e., disabling the boxes altogether, makes all fine
%\let\boxlst\lstinline

\begin{document}

Bla bla.


First time it works:\\
xxx \boxlst!{a|}! xxx 
\\
xxx \boxlst!aa|a! xxx
\\
xxx \boxlst!a{|}! xxx

Second time it works:\\
xxx \boxlst!{a|}! xxx 
\\
xxx \boxlst!aa|a! xxx
\\
xxx \boxlst!a{|}! xxx

%\lstinline!Test! xxx
\begin{lstlisting}
Include any "unboxed" listing here --- inline or
environment --- and it starts failing:
\end{lstlisting}

Now it fails:\\
xxx \boxlst!{a|}! xxx
\\
xxx \boxlst!aa|a! xxx
\\
xxx \boxlst!a{|}! xxx

Now it also fails:\\
xxx \boxlst!{a|}! xxx
\\
xxx \boxlst!aa|a! xxx
\\
xxx \boxlst!a{|}! xxx


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't want to use the switches `disable` and `enable` here. The problem is that `disable` will indeed completely turn off `microtype`, so that it doesn't have any chance of doing what you would want it to do. The first time around that is ok, while in the second case it is not: triggered by the inserted listing, the typewriter font is now and henceforth set up for protrusion. Because you then disable `microtype` again, this protrusion will not be deactivated. And this protrusion (of the opening brace `{`) is what makes the boxes unjustified.

So instead of using `dis/enable` (which are explicitly "undocumented"!) you should enclose the `lrbox` code with:

```
\microtypesetup{activate=false}% 
...
\microtypesetup{activate=true}%
```

Comment: One word: Wow! :)